# outlook addin debug or logs for Mac

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are developing an outlook Addin for Mac.
When the addin is manually deployed using "Custom Addins", basic javascript gets the function callback which is registered in manifest xml.
Now we want to HTTPS POST mail details to another server.

If I call below function in JS, it works.

```js
function post1() {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xhr.open("POST", "https://localhost:4431/something.aspx", true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
      name: "Name",
      phone: "11224"
    }));  
}
```

But below function doesnt work and the outlook spins waiting on addin

```js
function post2() {
  try{
    let response = await fetch('https://localhost:4431/something.aspx');
  } catch(err)
  {
    outputString = "got exception";
  }
}
```

I doubt if fetch api is supported to be run from Addin script and below is the runtime log

***2/15/22 6:24:42 PM   Unexpected  Runtime [Error] [Log] {"message":"SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'fetch'. Expected ';' after variable declaration.","fileName":"https://localhost:3000/app.js","lineNumber":16}

2/15/22 6:24:53 PM  Unexpected  Runtime [Error] [Log] {"message":"Script error.","fileName":"","lineNumber":0}***

Comment: Do you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch in the add-in?

Answer (score 0):

When I corrected it to use async function, it worked.

```js
async function post2() {
  try{
    let response = await fetch('https://localhost:4431/something.aspx');
  } catch(err)
  {
    outputString = "got exception";
  }
}
```

I got this exact error when I ran the same javascript in html using chrome browser.

But the error in outlook log was not clear enough to know the exact problem.